# Right align values using @html.grid column.format

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, grid, text-alignment

How can I right align values when using the columns.add() inside a @html.grid().columns collection?

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Unidades).Columns(columns => {
columns.Add()
    .Encoded(false)
    .Sanitized(false)
    .Titled("Volume")
    .RenderValueAs(o => CustomRenderingOfColumnVolume(o));
columns.Add(m => m.VolumeCorrigido)
    .Titled("Volume")
    .Format("{0:N4}")
    .Sanitized(false)
    .Encoded(false);
});

@helper CustomRenderingOfColumnVolume(Dto.ObjectDto item) { 
        <span style="text-align: right; width: 100%">@string.Format("{0:N2}", item.Volume)</span>
}
```

I've already tried, without success:
- Custom .toString() from column object, but it does not permit custom format
- Using .Format("{0,10}").SetWidth(30) like we do to right align using custom string format
- Using @helper (see CustomRenderingOfColumnVolume above on code)
- other many things I cannot remember now

I've found no documentation, no tutorial, no google specific result for this component. I just need some stuff to study or a tip to right align the column values. I will appreciate any help, even CSS for the column component in @helper.

Comment: You can apply a class to your column: `columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Titled("Volume").RenderValueAs(o => CustomRenderingOfColumnVolume(o)).Css("align-right")`; and then in your CSS: `.align-right{text-align: right !important}`

Comment: @RahulSharma thank you very much. It's working, and it is so simple. How can I mark your comment as a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a class to your column:

`columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Titled("Volume").RenderValueAs(o => CustomRenderingOfColumnVolume(o)).Css("align-right")`;

And then in your CSS:

`.align-right{text-align: right !important}`

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine send another solution, similar to @RahulSharma did, but without using the @helper neither a css named class, just a method from the column object:

```
<style>
    /*Simple css hack to right align text*/
    td[data-name='Volume'] {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>

[...]
columns.Add(m => m.Volume)
    .Titled("Volume")
    .Format("{0:N4}")
    .Sanitized(false)
    .Encoded(false);
});
```

I've tested both and worked very well. Thanks for all.